# Split string with delimiter as whitespace but it preserve whitespace within doubleqoutes and also doubleqoutes in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, split

Split string with delimiter as whitespace but it should preserve whitespace within doubleqoutes and also doubleqoutes in Python

```
a='Append ",","te st1",input To output'
```

output list should be like below

```
['Append', '",","te st1",input', 'To', 'output']
```

Comment: `str.split(" ")`, Don't use `str` as a variable name, its already reserved, use something else

Comment: Thanks i updated . could you please help me how to achieve the above scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using regular expressions:

```
re.findall("(?:\".*?\"|\S)+", a)
```

gives

```
['Append', '",","te st1",input', 'To', 'output']
```

**Update:** Improved pattern that includes escaping:

```
re.findall("(?:\".*?[^\\\"]\"|\S)+", a)
```

Please note that this also matches the empty string `""` by means of the `\S` part of the pattern.

**Note:** Old answer below for archival purposes:

The obvious answer would be to use `shlex` like this:

```
>>> shlex.split('Append ",","te st1",input To output')
['Append', ',,te st1,input', 'To', 'output']
```

This will remove the quotes, unfortunately. Anyways, this kind of problem can be solved with a simple state machine. The performance might be sub-par, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import string

def split_string_whitespace(s):
    current_token = []
    result = []
    state = 0
    for c in s + " ":
        if state == 0:
            if c in string.whitespace:
                if current_token:
                    result.append("".join(current_token))
                    current_token = []
            else:
                current_token.append(c)
                if c == '"':
                    state = 1
        else:
            current_token.append(c)
            if c == '"':
                state = 0
    return result

print split_string_whitespace('Append ",","te st1",input To output')
```

The script yields:

```
['Append', '",","te st1",input', 'To', 'output']
```

I'm pretty sure one could construct something with the `re` submodule, so I'm waiting for that answer, too :)

Comment: Thanks , I'm also expecting same kind of answer like using re or shlex. Because i'm going to process millions of records . I guess regular expression is better way instead of loop through.

Comment: `shlex` will remove the quotes, unfortunately, but I guess you have found out about that already.

Comment: @Vicky Does your data really have multiple quoted sections within a single token and they do not always enclose a token? Otherwise you could just use the `csv` module.

Comment: Smells like a `csv` problem tbh

Comment: Actually i'm trying to read the data from Excel file. Also i tried CSV reader seems like im not able to preserve the whitespace within the double quotes.

Comment: in that case add a reference to csv to your question and add the csv tag also.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple generator function, maintaining the current "quotation state":

```
def splitter(s):
    i, quoted = 0, False
    for n, c in enumerate(s+' '):
        if c == '"':
            quoted = not quoted
        elif c == ' ' and not quoted:
            if n > i:
                yield s[i:n]
            i = n+1

list(splitter(a))
# ['Append', '",","te st1",input', 'To', 'output']
```